# Fraction of ... IS or ARE?

Tags: grammaticality, verb-agreement

Should I use

*What fraction of the residents **are** married?*

or

*What fraction of the residents **is** married?*

Technically, as *fraction* is singular, I would use the latter version. Am I correct?

Comment: This is often a tough one.  I would go for "are" above, but "is" in other contexts, and I can't give you a "rule".

Comment: It would also be more usual to ask *what percentage of the residents are married*. And there I would always use *are*.

Comment: I assume the rule of thumb is that if the "amount" probably resolves to "more than one" then the plural is used. If you know in advance the answer can only be singular then the question would be "Which one of the residents *is* married".

Comment: "are" -- "is" in the example sounds strange, like some sort of hypercorrection.  The *reason* it's "are" is not clear to me -- perhaps it's because the subject could refer to many people. "Approximately two people have left" (subject is plural though it could refer to one person)

Comment: I'm very sure this Q has been dealt with before.

Comment: The duplicate @tchrist referenced gives a definitive answer to this question: ***are*** in this context and in most others.

Answer (score -1):

No doubt, it should be 'are'.  Fraction is not commonly used in the mathematical sense ('technically' refers to 'mathematically').  For eg, A small fraction of voters will abstain from voting due to the boycott call.  It can be seen in other usages as well - http://www.azadvocacy.org/press-a-media/media/253-just-a-fraction-of-voters-meet-id-deadline - Just a Fraction of Voters Meet I.D. Deadline. (not 'meets' if we want to use 'singular').

Comment: In the example with voters you provide, nothing indicates whether a plural or singular is used.